# KeyStore (API < 23) PrivateKey is removed

Tags: android, encryption, android-keystore

We use RSA-encryption for an application secret in our app. We generate the RSA-keys once the user is authenticated with our servers with the following approach for Android API < 23.

```
public KeyPair generateKeys(@NonNull String alias, Context context) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
    Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    endDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, 2);
    BigInteger serialNumber = BigInteger.valueOf(new PositiveSecureRandom().nextPositive()); // Custom class that only provides positive randoms

    // Context passed down is an activity context, if that matters anything
    kpg.initialize(new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context) 
            .setAlias(alias)
            .setAlgorithmParameterSpec(new RSAKeyGenParameterSpec(2048, RSAKeyGenParameterSpec.F4))
            .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + alias))
            .setStartDate(startDate.getTime())
            .setSerialNumber(serialNumber)
            .setEndDate(endDate.getTime())
            .build());

    KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();

    return keyPair;
}
```

The user is then able to authenticate with our servers using the secret encrypted with these keys, but not too many times.

After a certain amount of time, the keys seems to have mysteriously disappeared. Considering this occurs to relatively old (and bad) devices, I guess the application is restarted between successful generation and usage of keys, and the disappearance of our keys. When retrieving the keys with the below code the privateKeyEntry is null after trying to retrieve it from the KeyStore.

```
public KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry getPrivateKeyEntry(String alias) {
    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = null;
    try {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
        keyStore.load(null);
        privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
        if (privateKeyEntry == null) {
            // We're logging this occurance to the server here. I.e. we are 100% sure the keys are gone. 
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception occured", e);
    }
    return privateKeyEntry;
}
```

I've read quite a few blogposts about how the keystore is invalidating/dropping the keys if the user changes his/her screenlock, but this does not seem to be the case here. One customer has for instance gotten his keys removed three times in a day. Based on the demographics of these customers, I've also ruled out rooting of the phone. There are simply too many examples of non-tech-savy people with age > 60 this occurs to. To make matters even worse, we're not able to reproduce it in any of our test devices.

So what I'm wondering here is if anyone have ran into the same issues, and actually have been able to pinpoint why this occurs? Were you able to find any proper solution for this?

Comment: Could this be caused by system updates to the Android OS that the user installs on their handsets?